# Django 2.0 DateTimeField add by admin failure

Tags: python, django

This is pretty specific:
I have a dead simple model.

```
from django.db import models

class Update(models.Model):
    update = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I try to add an update in the admin panel, it foobars the whole thing, and gives me an error immediately saying:

```
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Any ideas?
Django 2.0.1, Python 3.5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Originally had made update a DateField, not a DateTimeField, and then when doing the migrations, had deleted the previous migration for migrating it to my server, but locally had not deleted it from the database, so it was trying to add a datetime into a date field in the database.